# Does ArcGIS Field Maps have photo direction?

Tags: arcgis-field-maps

Is there a way to automatically collect the direction the camera is facing when taking photos in field maps?

When adding a new collection point, and using the "take photo" feature right in the ArcGIS Field Maps app (not adding attachments from previously taken photos).